# Count cycles in a permutated list

Tags: python, list, algorithm, permutation

I am trying to make a function that counts the number of cycles within a permutated list.

I do sometimes get the right answer when running the code, but most times I receive an error message - and I am unable to figure out why.

My code is as follows:

```
def count_cycles(n):

    cycle_count = 0
    copy_list = []
    
    for element in n:
        copy_list.append(element)

    while len(copy_list) != 0:
        ran_num = random.choice(copy_list)

        while True:
            if n[ran_num] == ran_num:
                cycle_count = circle_count + 1
                if int(ran_num) in copy_list:
                    copy_list.remove(ran_num)
                    
                break
            
            else:
                n.insert(ran_num, ran_num)
                print(n, ran_num, copy_list)
                ran_num = n[ran_num + 1]
                
                print(ran_num)
                copy_list.remove(ran_num)
                    
                n.remove(ran_num)
                continue

    return print(cycle_count, n)
```

What I use is that I test with this permutated list with 3 cycles [2, 6, 0, 3, 1, 4, 5].

[`Picture of output from a correct and incorrect run`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2794e.png)

I used `print(n, ran_num, copy_list)` to assess the output as per the picture.

Comment: Please include the error message as text, not as a picture.

Comment: What is a "cycle" in this context? Why does [2, 6, 0, 3, 1, 4, 5] have 3 cycles?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one possibility:

```
p = [2, 6, 0, 3, 1, 4, 5]

cycles = set()
elts = set(range(len(p)))
while elts:
    cycle = []
    x0 = elts.pop()
    cycle.append(x0)
    x = p[x0]
    while x != x0:
        cycle.append(x)
        x = p[x]
    elts -= set(cycle)
    cycles.add(tuple(cycle))
    
print(cycles)
```

It gives:

```
{(0, 2), (1, 6, 5, 4), (3,)}
```

Then to get the number of cycles you can use `len(cycles)`.

Comment: It appears that you can reduce the runtime of this solution from quadratic to linear by changing the line `while x not in cycle`, which uses a list containment call. Either keeping a separate cycle_set or comparing `x` to the start of the cycle should be enough.

Comment: Good point, thank you. I incorporated it in the answer.

Comment: Hi. Thanks a ton for the help on this. I am pretty new to Python, and always great to read and understand other people's code/way of tackling a problem. I see some similarities in terms of the overall thinking, but with your code is more efficient. Much appreciated, that you took the time to answer my question :) Enjoy the weekend.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the existing answer, `sympy` provides some functionality to work with permutations. In this case, you could use the following:

```
from sympy.combinatorics import Permutation
p = Permutation([2, 6, 0, 3, 1, 4, 5])
num_cycles = p.cycles # 3
```